# I have a task where my "while-loop" has to stop before a certain value, but it doesn't. (Code is attached)

Tags: php, html

```
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="get">
            <input type="number" name="anschaffungswert"> anschaffungswert <br>
            <input type="number" name="wertminderung"> Wertminderun in % (z.B. 99) <br>
            <input type="number" name="restwert"> Restwert <br><br>
            
            <input type="submit" name="gesendet" value="berechnen">
        </form>

        <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['gesendet']))
        {   
            //Variablen hinzufügen
            $anschaffungswert = $_GET['anschaffungswert'];
            $wertminderung = $_GET['wertminderung'] * 0.01;
            $restwert = $_GET['restwert'];
            $jahr = 0;

            //Erste echo Ausgabe
            while ($anschaffungswert>$restwert) {
                $jahr = $jahr + 1;
                $anschaffungswert = $anschaffungswert * $wertminderung;
                echo "$restwert Restwert $anschaffungswert Anschaffungswert $jahr Jahr <br>";
            }

        }
```

I need $anschaffungswert to show up on my echo before it's less than $restwert and not after it's already less.
It's asked by my teacher and she wouldn't accept in any other way.

Comment: change `$anschaffungswert = $anschaffungswert * $wertminderung;` to `$anschaffungswert = $anschaffungswert - ($anschaffungswert * $wertminderung);` or if you want it shorter `$anschaffungswert -= $anschaffungswert * $wertminderung;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to know if `$anschaffungswert` will be less than `$restwert` in the next iteration. To do this, just check if it is lower after calculating and stop the loop there using [break](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php).

```
            while ($anschaffungswert>$restwert) {
               $jahr = $jahr + 1;
               $anschaffungswert = $anschaffungswert * $wertminderung;
               if ($anschaffungswert > $restwert) break;
               echo "$restwert Restwert $anschaffungswert Anschaffungswert $jahr Jahr <br>";
            }
```

You could also check if the next value of `$anschaffungswert` is too high in your while-condition.